# Can I cast a unsigned long to size_t without loss of data?

Tags: c++, casting, size-t

`size_t` is a unsigned integer type, that is returned by (for example) `sizeof`. Can I therefore cast an `unsigned long` into it? What problems could occur? Should I use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, or another?

EDIT:

I want to convert a string into an `unsigned long` and then cast that to `size_t`:

```
size_t StringHandling::ConvertSize_T (std::string& input, int base)
{
    return static_cast<size_t>(std::stoul(input, 0, base));
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to cast it? What problem is this solving?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to cast to what, the direction matters.

Comment: depends on the size of `unsigned int` and `size_t`

Comment: Your title, and your body, say polar opposite things. What exactly are you trying to do, why, and what is the problem?

Comment: Im sorry, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can you safely cast a `std::size_t` to `unsigned long`?

Generally… **no**.

If `unsigned long` has the same width as `std::size_t` on your system, then you'd get away with it with a simple `static_cast`. But why take the chance? If it doesn't, and this is by no means unlikely on systems that exist today, you'll be potentially truncating *half* your value space — if you're going from 64-bit to 32-bit, that's eighteen quintillion, four hundred and forty-six quadrillion, seven hundred and forty-four trillion possible values lost!!

If you get a `std::size_t` from a function that decided it needed that type to represent all possible values of its result, keep a `std::size_t`.

---

#### Can you safely cast an `unsigned long` to `std::size_t`?

Sure. Technically I don't think there's any reason the latter *has* to be wider than (or even at least as wide as) the former (it only has to be at least 16 bits wide), but you'll be hard-pressed to find any system for which that isn't the case.

---

#### Can you safely mix `std::stoul` and `std::size_t`?

This depends on your project requirements. Per the above, converting the result of `std::stoul` to `std::size_t` is probably fine.

But, what about the `std::stoul` itself? Are you expecting the string to contain numeric values that fit in a `std::size_t` but not in an `unsigned long`? If so, your string parsing is at fault here, not the casting, and you will need to find a more appropriate way to extract such a large number from your stream.

---

**tl;dr:** Try not to mix types. Work out what the expected numeric range is for your input, pick an appropriate type accordingly, then *stick with it* throughout your pipeline.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, casting 64-bit values into a 32-bit variable would truncate ((2^64)-(2^32)) values, which is a lot more than half and a lot more than 4 billion :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, since you say such an occurrence isn’t unlikely, *which* modern system has `sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(size_t)`? Even if there are some (not an expert), I’d probably question their characterisation of encountering them as “likely”: none of the [common data models](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) have this property.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't say `sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(size_t)` is likely. I said `sizeof(unsigned long) != sizeof(size_t)` isn't unlikely. I was thinking specifically of `sizeof(unsigned long) < sizeof(size_t)`, which is true at least on every single 64-bit Windows PC.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Hmm but that case is unproblematic for OP. EDIT: I’m just realising that I had missed that your entire first section refers to the conversion in the inverse direction of what OP wants. Fair enough, though I feel that others might make the same mistake as me, and mis-apply the advice to OP’s situation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It didn't when I wrote it. :) The question has undergone some changes during its lifetime. I suppose the first section can probably be removed now, but I'd be sad

Answer (score 1):

If you mean in a theoretical, language lawyer way, then the answer is no:

> According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), `size_t` is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit (see sections 7.17 and 7.18.3).

All the C99 standard guarantees is that it's at least a 16-bit type.

In the real world on modern Intel/ARM architectures however, `size_t` is usually the native register size, so 32-bit on a 32-bit architecture, and 64-bit on a 64-bit architecture. You should always be able to store an `int` in a `size_t`, but not the other way around.

> Should I use static or reinterpret cast, or another?

This cast is a static cast, reinterpret is for reinterpreting pointers to different unrelated types.

Comment: OP changed the type in their question from `unsigned int` to `unsigned long`. But I don’t think this materially changes this answer.